# awk script to print in between result before the final result

Tags: bash, awk

```
DATE_ID TOT_OP_MAIN_PAID_MNT
20140201        0
20140201          -100
20140201        -9
20140201        0
20140201        0
20140201        0
20140201        0
20140201        -127.5
20140201        0
20140201        -126.4
20140201        0
20140202             23
20140202             -233
20140202             0
20140203             55
20140203             90
20140203            -13
```

I have a million of records on txt files presented as above with each txt file having record on a single day, I would like to know how to have a output which will give me a total sum of `TOT_OP_MAIN_PAID_MNT` of each day but also the total sum at the end of all files:

Here a sample of how I am expecting the output to be:

```
DATE_ID   TOTAL
20140201  -362.9
20140202  -210
20140203  132

          -440,9
```

the awk code I am using:

```
awk -F, 'FNR == 5 {print $1} { sum += $6 } END { print sum }' CAS01.txt CAS02.txt CAS03.txt
```

but the output I got looks like

```
20140201
20140202
20140228
-1.7445e+09
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for something like this:

```
awk 'NR==1 {next}
     {a[$1]+=$2}
     END {for (i in a) {print i, a[i]; tot+=a[i]} 
          print "TOTAL", tot}' file
```

For your given input it returns:

```
20140201 -362.9
20140202 -210
20140203 132
TOTAL -440.9
```

#### Explanation

- `NR==1 {next}` skip the first line.
- `{a[$1]+=$2}` for every line, keep an array containing `a[day]=value`.
- `END {}` when finished, print the results.
- `for (i in a) {print i, a[i]; tot+=a[i]}` print the totals for every day and keep a counter for all the values.
- `print "TOTAL", tot` print the total count.

If you want to keep the header, you can store it for `NR==1`:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {header=$0; next} {a[$1]+=$2} END {print header; for (i in a) {print i, a[i]; tot+=a[i]} print "TOTAL", tot}' a | column -t
DATE_ID   TOT_OP_MAIN_PAID_MNT
20140201  -362.9
20140202  -210
20140203  132
TOTAL     -440.9
```

Comment: I would do `NR>1{a[$1]+=$2}` and leave out `NR==1 {next}` personally but thats because i don't like using `next`s

Comment: Yes, well I like to explicitly indicate the wrong cases so that they can be handled differently (for example when getting the header).

Comment: Well done, thank you it's exactly what i was looking for but in the result i have another line  <br/>

20140201 -4.50529e+08  <br/>
20140202 -5.3382e+08  <br/>
20140228 -7.60153e+08  <br/>
DATE_ID 0   <--------------- I have that line in the result  <br/>
TOTAL -1.7445e+09  <br/>

Comment: @JefAime this is probably because `DATE_ID` is in another line, not the 1st. Check the condition `NR==1{next}` or the `NR==1 {header=$0; next}`, that skips it. Otherwise it is an index for the counter.

Comment: @fedorqui i have only DATE_ID in the header line so normally NR==1 {header=$0; next} have to skip it. I don't know why it appeared again

Comment: @JefAime it is not clear to me, neither. You can update your post with the code you are using and the input you have.

Comment: THE CODE awk -F, 'NR==1 {header=$0; next}
{a[$1]+=$6}
END {for (i in a) {print i, a[i]; tot+=a[i]}
print "TOTAL", tot}' CAS01.txt CAS02.txt CAS03.txt

THE OUTPUT 20140201 -4.50529e+08
20140202 -5.3382e+08
20140228 -7.60153e+08
DATE_ID 0
TOTAL -1.7445e+09

Comment: THE CODE awk -F, 'NR==1 {header=$0; next}
{a[$1]+=$6}
END {for (i in a) {print i, a[i]; tot+=a[i]}
print "TOTAL", tot}' CAS01.txt CAS02.txt CAS03.txt

Comment: @JefAime so you are processing multiple files? If so, it is `FNR==1` what you have to use, because it refers to each single file, whereas `NR` will just match the first line in the first file.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    print("DATE_ID", "TOTAL")
}

$1 ~ /[[:digit:]]/ {
    a[$1]+=$2;total+=$2
}

END{
    for(i in a) {
        print i,a[i]
    }
    print "\t"total
}
```

One liner.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print("DATE_ID", "TOTAL")} $1 ~ /[[:digit:]]/ {a[$1]+=$2;total+=$2} END{for(i in a) {print i,a[i]}; print "\t"total}' file.txt
```

Output:

```
DATE_ID TOTAL
20140202 -210
20140203 132
20140201 -362.9
         -440.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following shell script is what you need

```
#! /bin/bash
for file in $@
do
awk -F' ' 'BEGIN{
} {
    print $0
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        sum[i]+=$i
}
END {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        printf("%.2lf ",sum[i]) 
    print("\n")
}' $file
done
```

Save it in col_sum.sh, and just run `sh col_sum.sh a.txt b.txt c.txt` in linux shell.

Note: when the sum is too large, `print` will output scientific notation. What you need is [Format-Control](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Control-Letters.html)!

Comment: Aw great i was struggling to get a proper output format. Thanks